# How to return href of a class with javascript

Tags: javascript, href

Hello I can not figure this out. I am a noob with Javascriptbut I think this is the last piece of the puzzle I can't figure out.

```
<div class="imgContainer DetailImage">                                                  <!-- Start extra info -->       <div id="p7IGM_1" class="p7IGM02 IGMnoscript">           <div class="p7IGM_wrapper">             <div 
<div id="p7IGMimage_1" 
class="p7IGM02_image"><a id="p7IGMimlink_1" class="p7IGM02-image-link viewImage" 
rel="viewImage" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/ResourceFiles195/LGE/LargeImages/55LH5750_Primary.jpg" 
title="55LH5750">
<img src= "/_resizeplugin/timthumb.php?src=https://www.mywebsite.com/ResourceFiles195/LGE/LargeImages/55LH5750_Primary.jpg&w=400&h=400&q=80"
```

If this works to call img src;

```
function myFunc() {
  var img = document.querySelector(".imgContainer.DetailImage img");

  return img.src
}
```

Why doesn’t this work at all to get the href? What am I doing wrong?

```
function myFunc() {
  var img = document.querySelector(".imgContainer.DetailImage href");

  return img
}
```

Comment: 4 down votes on my question? Do I not understand the point of this community? According to the description "This site is all about getting answers."

Comment: `document.getElementById("p7IGMimage_1").querySelector(".p7IGM02-image-link").href`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use

```
document.querySelector(".imgContainer.DetailImage a").href
```

Comment: first you check document.querySelector(".imgContainer.DetailImage") is giving any object or not . Other wise it must work.

Comment: Without the .href it returns "[object HTMLDivElement]" is that what you mean?

Comment: i have updated the answer please take a look, i forgot to mention "a" at last

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.